# Simple screen refresh in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5, afhttprequestoperation

I have a scene with json gets a facebook likes. I need automatic update for that scene (the screen must reload). when new data (in this case - facebook likes counts has been changed). I tried all samples over the web, but couldn't implement that.

ViewController.m:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *FaceBookLikes = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSString *FBlikes = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"faceBookUrlField"];
NSString *FBLstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@", FBlikes];
[FaceBookLikes GET:FBLstr parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    self.posts = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
    self.post = self.posts [@"likes"];
    NSLog(@"FB LIKES: %@", self.post);
    labelFacebookLikesCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.post];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

I will welcome any solving:

1. update (refresh screen) when json counts has changed.
2. update by time (for example) each 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invalidate whatever view you want to refresh.

So in your case,

`[self.viewToRefresh setNeedsDisplay];`

Call this after you have updated your values.

Comment: This will work only if the view in question is doing custom drawing with `-drawRect`.

Comment: Where to paste it? I get error "property not found on object of type ViewController ...

Comment: Maybe you can suggest a simple Scene Refresh (by time). How to do that?

Comment: @МаксимЗуев `viewToRefresh` should be replaced with your view. But this method probably won’t work in your case (see my previous comment).